# c# asp.net how to add video source filename to different media type with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, html5-video

I would like to update a global C# variable using javascript.  I think that I cannot do it since javascript is client side.  I can pass the source filename of the video the javascript but how could I update the video source tags in the modal?  Any help would be appreciated.

here is my code:

**watch-videos.aspx**

```
<div class="table-responsive has-margin-bottom">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" 
        Width="100%" OnItemDataBound="DataList2_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
                data-videoname='<%# Eval("title") %>' data-videofile='<%= fileDirectory %><%# Eval("filename") %>' >
                <img src='<%= fileDirectory %><%# Eval("filename") %>.png' class="img-responsive" />
                <h3><%# Eval("title") %></h3>
            </button>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>    


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" ></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <video id="video1" class="center-block" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" width="640" height="480"  >

                    <source src="<%=videoFile %>.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    <source src="<%=videoFile %>.ogv" type="video/ogv" />
                    <source src="<%=videoFile %>.wmv" type="video/wmv" />

                    Video is not supported by your browser or computer

                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Master Page**

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
        var myFilename = button.data('videofile') //videofilename for source
        var myTitlename = button.data('videoname')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-title').text(myTitlename)
    })
```

Comment: You want to update tags on clientside from serverside data videoFile variable?

Comment: I can update the data tags for the javascript script to know.  I need to pass that tag in javascript to the modal.  Can I do something similar like what I did (took it from getbootstrap.com example) to update the modal title.  I need to let the <video> know the source information

Answer (score 0):

This will update video src to what is in data-videofile attribute of each button when clicked:

```
<button onclick="$('#video1 source').attr('src', $(this).data('videofile'));" class=...
```

Comment: your code did not worked.  I tried using your code in the Master page script with some modification and did not work either. I added to the last line of the script the following:   modal.find('#video1 source').attr('src', myFilename)

Comment: Any errors? Did it update the src in the underlying HTML when button is clicked?

Comment: no, I gave up and use ajaxcontrol on asp.net to open the modal from codebehind.  thanks you anyways